# Accessing database many times in android. what about performance?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

In my application, I'm retrieving content from the database very often. So I'm likely to access data from database when it is required. For example, even within an activity I'll open and close the database 3 to 4 times. Is this enough to cause performance to suffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would really depend on the amount of data you are reading and how complicated the queries are. Personally I wouldn't worry about unless you can notice the performance issue, why fix a problem that doesn't exist. That said if you are noticing performance problems and think the database may be the cause you can try the following:

- Cache database reads so they only have to be done when something is updated.
- Wrap database writes in transactions so the disk writes are done all in one go.
- Only read the data you need. For instance if you have a list the displays 3 out of the 20 fields only read the 3 fields you need.

Comment: Although i agree generally with your post I'm not sure i agree with "why fix a problem that doesn't exist" remember one problem which might not be noticeable is that of battery drain. We as programmer's should be aware and responsible for making our applications as efficient as possible. Not only to improve user experience of fast snappy performance but also to help conserve the phone's battery life.

Comment: You still need to identify that the problem exists first. No point making optimisations if you don't have some basis to evaluate they actually worked.

Comment: Most of time we don't follow the coding standards.but some how we manage to get desired result.Reason for this may be lack of experience or knowledge in the language.It should not happen no?

Comment: from your answer i got that it not really matters how many time we access the database. its only the matter of amount of data transmission...

Comment: Yes. That and the complexity of the queries.